# text over img hover with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm a complete beginner at coding and I've already searched here but I couldn't really find a proper solution to my problem.

I'm trying to get a text to appear in place of the image when I hover over the image with the mouse.
Unfortunately jQuery has to be used, I know it can be done by just using CSS.

So far I have the following which I found on here:

In the head:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    $('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('.child').fadeIn();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.child').fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<div class='parent'>
<img src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg' alt='image'/>
<div class='child'>
<p>Random text.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent
{
    position:relative;
}
.child
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    padding:10px;

    display:none;
}
```

Thank you for an easy tip or explanation on what I'm doing wrong and how I can solve that problem.

Edit:

This is my full code in my PHP file:

```
    echo "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=\"en\">
    <head>
        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
        <title>Test Blog</title>    
     
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    
      $('.gallery-item').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.img-title').fadeIn(300);
      }, function() {
        $(this).find('.img-title').fadeOut(100);
      });
    
    });
    </script>
     
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>
    
    
    <div class=\"wrapper clearfix\">
    
      <figure class=\"gallery-item\">
        <img src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg' alt='image'>
        <figcaption class=\"img-title\">
          <h5>Random text.</h5>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    
    
    </div>
```

And there it continues with a dropdown menu routing to the other pages.
The CSS code is in my CSS file which I linked to above (the link is correct since all the other CSS code is working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.gallery-item').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeIn(300);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.img-title').fadeOut(100);
  });

});
```

```css
.gallery {
  width: 25em;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.gallery-item {
  height: auto;
  width: 48.618784527%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-item:first-child {
  margin-right: 2.762430939%;
}

.gallery-item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-item:hover .img-title {}

.img-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
}

.img-title h5 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 33%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper clearfix">

  <figure class="gallery-item">
    <img src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg' alt='image'>
    <figcaption class="img-title">
      <h5>Random text.</h5>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>



</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already had this solution. But it's for uni and this solution is not accepted as we have to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: I edit my answer, was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you, yes this is what I'm looking for however if I copy it into my PHP file I can't seem to get it to work. I will update my post with my full code I guess I have to implement it in a different way somehow.

Comment: is your css/js file inside your html page?

Comment: I just edited my post with how my file looks like right now.

Comment: put your script under your jquery cdn

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation yet for it to show (at least that's how I understood it). :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the size of the overly - I did that with the position settings below. Also, I erased the opacity setting. Not sure what else you want, but basically it works now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('.child').fadeIn();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('.child').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.child p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <img src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg' alt='image' />
  <div class='child'>
    <p>Random text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working if I run the snippet here but when I copy everything in my PHP storm document it's not working whatsoever. So jut to be clear: I add the first snippet into the head of my document between <script> tags. The second one goes into my CSS file obviously and the third one into the body of my document, right? Sorry as I said: complete beginner. :(

Comment: yes, that's the way these snippets work, too. Basically, you should set the size of the parent container, so the overlay can refer to something in terms of size when you give it "width: 100% and "height: 100%" (as an absolutely positioned element, it needs to have a size, which in my snippet I replaced with the top/bottom/left/right = 0 settings.)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you out.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
        //alert();
        $(this).children('.child').show().fadeIn(200);//have some timeout for fading in
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.child').fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

```css
.parent
{
    position:relative;
}
.child
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1.0;
    padding:10px;
    display:none;
    /*
    add width and height attribute to the elem
    */
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<img src='https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg' alt='image'/>
<div class='child'>
<p>Random text.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working if I run the snippet here but when I copy everything in my PHP storm document it's not working whatsoever. So just to be clear: I add the first snippet into the head of my document between <script> tags. The second one goes into my CSS file obviously and the third one into the body of my document, right? Sorry as I said: complete beginner. :(